# Pulumi EKS cluster: @pulumi/eks vs. @pulumi/aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, pulumi

I'm trying to create an AWS EKS cluster with Pulumi and it seems two components exists:

- [`@pulumi/eks`](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-eks) providing a [`Cluster`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/eks/cluster/#package-details) component
- [`@pulumi/aws`](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-aws) providing an [`eks/Cluster`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/aws/eks/cluster/) component

`@pulumi/eks` seems to be higher level but I cannot find a documentation specifying the concrete difference between those, and if one is preferred depending on use cases.

What's the difference between those two components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@pulumi/eks/Cluster` is a [component resource](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/resources/#components) that is built on top of `@pulumi/aws/eks/Cluster` and other resources to simplify provisioning of EKS clusters. Its goal is to make common scenarios achievable with a handful of lines of code, as opposed to the involved model of raw AWS resources.

You can find some usage examples in

- [AWS Crosswalk: AWS Elastic Kubernetes Service](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/crosswalk/aws/eks/)
- [Easily Create and Manage AWS EKS Kubernetes Clusters with Pulumi](https://www.pulumi.com/blog/easily-create-and-manage-aws-eks-kubernetes-clusters-with-pulumi/).

I suggest you start with `@pulumi/eks` and see if it works well for you.

Comment: Thanks, looking at the source code `@pulumi/eks` is indeed using Go import from `pulumi/aws` such as `github.com/pulumi/pulumi-aws/sdk/v4/go/aws/eks`.